# How should I interpret this sentence structure?

Tags: meaning

> Glove shall be worn by employees whose work exposes them to injuries,
>   such as exposure to cuts, burns, harmful physical hazards, chemical
>   agents or electrical hazards **which are encountered and capable of
>   causing injury or impairments**.

Does the bold part apply to "harmful physical hazards, chemical agents or electrical hazards" or "chemical agents or electrical hazards"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bold part applies to "cuts, burns, harmful physical hazards, chemical agents or electrical hazards" which they encounter at work.